# If I open Colorbox in CodeIgniter its shows multiple time after click on search button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

**index.php**

here I call `div`:

```
<div id="dd">
 <?php
   $this->load->view('indexresult');
  ?>
</div>
```

**indexresult.php**

here I get the `id` from `click` on `href`. After it I have `post` and `put` in `session`. After back I have load `div`

```
$('#category li a').click(function() 
{
  var SearchId = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#loading-image').show();
  $.post("<?php echo site_url('AllResult');?>",{SearchId:SearchId},function(data)
  {
    $("#dd").load('home/indexresult');       
  });   
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ajax").colorbox();
  $(".Login").colorbox({innerWidth: "500px",innerHeight: 320px",initialWidth:              false,initialHeight: false});
  $(".mapajax").colorbox({});
  $(".register").colorbox({initialWidth: false,initialHeight: false});
});
```

using class="Login", it open login color box.

```
<a href = "<?php echo site_url('home/loginpopup')?>" class="Login">Login</a>
```

First time Colorbox open  it works ok, but after `click` on search it open multiple Colorbox Instaces.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more the problem?

Comment: click on login its open colorbox. problem is that when i am opening colorbox first time then its open one time. its OK. but when i click on search(getting search id in session)and click on login then its open colorbox over colorbox. my need that its open only one time at any time.